# Create convex path for outline provider

Tags: android, path, android-custom-view, paint, convex

I try to create convex path for outline provider. I need a rectangular with rounded top left and top right corners.
There are one method which able to do this, but question: what wrong with my convex path?. It draws on paint like a convex, and geometrically should be fine.

(yes, I know about public void addRoundRect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, @NonNull float[] radii, @NonNull Direction dir))

There is implementation of my ConvexView

```
val Int.toPx: Int
    get() = (this * Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt()

class ConvexView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val paint = Paint().apply {
        isAntiAlias = true
        color = Color.RED
        strokeWidth = 5f
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    }

    private val convexPath = Path()

    val r = 24.toPx.toFloat()
    val d = r * 2

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        with (convexPath) {
            reset()
            arcTo(0f, 0f, d, d, -90f, -90f, true)
            lineTo(0f, measuredHeight.toFloat())
            lineTo(measuredWidth.toFloat(), measuredHeight.toFloat())
            lineTo(measuredWidth.toFloat(), r)
            arcTo(measuredWidth.toFloat() - d, 0f,
                measuredWidth.toFloat(), d,
                0f, -90f, true)
            lineTo(r, 0f)
        }
        Log.d("CONVEX", "Path is convex = ${convexPath.isConvex}")
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        canvas?.save()
        canvas?.drawPath(convexPath, paint)
        canvas?.restore()
    }
}
```

And result:
[image]

But path still not convex

Answer (score 1):

In the second arcTo() call, you need to specify the last parameter, forceMoveTo=false. arcTo(.... , true) terminates the path once. So it's drawing two separate paths that can never be convex.